# Why my pattern doesn't work? re.match("abc*bcd*", "abc/blahblah/bcd/adf")

Tags: python

Trying to return True in this case.

```
re.match("abc*bcd*", "abc/blahblah/bcd/adf")
```

Is my pattern wrong?

`*` means it can be any or many number of characters. I really don't understand why it's printing `None`

I'm running Python 2.7

Comment: "abc.sdfbcd.sldfjsdf" ...?  it's weird.

Comment: `*` means any number of _previous_ character, i.e. zero or more `c` or `d` letters in your case. Try `.*` for any character, e.g. `"abc.*bcd.*"`. I suggest you to use an online tool such as https://regex101.com/ to experiment on regexes.

Comment: Successfully building a remotely complex re is an iterative process best approached by starting with something that matches, e.g. “abc” then adding ONE term at a time. You would have found that abc* matched, then “abc*b would not match so you could investigate why. Like writing code, starting from something that works then adding ONE new thing and checking it, rinse and repeat, is much more likely to succeed than trying to write the whole thing then not knowing why on earth it doesn’t work.

Comment: Don't get confused with the glob command line syntax (like `*.py`) where `*` is not a quantifier but a wildcard on its own.

Comment: Thank you all :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change pattern to `abc.*bcd.*`
Your pattern will match strings like `abcccccbcdddddd`

Answer (score 1):

The `*` character applies to the pattern to its left. So in this case, you're allowing any number of `c`s and later any number of `d`s. You can use the dot `.` to mean any character.

```
re.match("abc.*bcd.*", "abc/blahblah/bcd/adf")
```